# What happens if you reroll and the new highest die is lower than the original?

Tags: cthulhu-dark

I was reading the [Cthulhu Dark](http://catchyourhare.com/files/Cthulhu%20Dark.pdf) rules again, and I noticed something that wasn’t specified.

The section on rerolling says, in part:

> If you included your Insanity die in the roll and you’re not happy with the result, you may reroll (all the dice). If you didn’t include your Insanity die before, you may add it now and reroll.
>
> Afterwards, look at the new result. As before, the highest die shows how well you do.

It does not say anything about what happens if the highest die *after* rerolling is lower than the highest die before the reroll. **Do you still use the new roll if the highest die is lower than the higher die before rerolling?**

Comment: This is the second question you've asked about the initial free version of the game. The website on the last page is current and you can purchase an expanded version of the rules there, with more advice on running the game and several sample scenarios.

Comment: @Glazius that seems interesting, I might check it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You gave up the old result. You get the new one.

> If, when you reroll, you roll a lower result, that lower result stands. You can, of course, roll again.
>
> -- *Cthulhu Dark*, p. 20